# Remove a word in file based on length

Tags: c

I have a sample text file like this:

```
a
aa
abc
abcde
abcdegdsak
adfjwoejvd
fasjowmcvfded
dfjweeojrm
gg
c
```

What I want is to do is:

Remove words that are longer than 5 digits (ex: "abcdegdsak", "adfjwoejvd", etc).

** Note: I will need the text file that has no longer than 5 digits word later in the code.

What is the best solution?

How to do the "remove" part? Here's what I have so far:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int doRemove(int length)
{
        FILE *ptr_file;
        char buf[1000];

        ptr_file =fopen("sample.txt","r");
        if (!ptr_file)
            return 1;

        while (fgets(buf,1000, ptr_file)!=NULL){
            if(strlen(buf) == length){
              // remove it from this file 
            } else {
              // stay in this file & print for debugging
              printf("%s",buf);
            }

    fclose(ptr_file);
        return 0;
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: You can write the words that meet your requirements to a separate file. Is that not acceptable?

Comment: Do you need to remove them from the input text file ? If yes, then you need to copy all words that are shorter than the required length to another file, and at the end remove the original file and rename the other file to the original file.

Comment: @VHS That's a good idea actually. Any sample code / tutorial for that?

Comment: @MichaelWalz I can remove them directly in the input file or I can create a new one. The thing is I need to use that input file (no longer 5 words) later in my code.

Comment: Look at my previous comment. You cannot remove word from the middle of an existing file.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample code that will write those words that meet your required condition (words greater than a certain length) to a separate new file.

```
int doRemove(int length)
{
        FILE *ptr_file;
        FILE *newFile;
        char buf[1000];

        ptr_file =fopen("sample.txt","r");
        newFile = fopen("output.txt","w");
        if (!ptr_file)
            return 1;

        while (fgets(buf,1000, ptr_file)!=NULL){
            if(strlen(buf) > length){
              // remove it from this file 
            } else {
              // stay in this file & print for debugging
              printf("%s",buf);
              fprintf(newFile, "%s", buf);
            }
        }

    fclose(ptr_file);
    fclose(newFile);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You didn't care about the `\n` that `fgets` put at the end of the line,

Comment: Well, I have actually in a way. I have the condition as `>` instead of `>=`.

Comment: Also, my answer was to give the OP an idea as to how he can achieve his goal. If more accuracy is desired, we can improve this answer as a community.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Hey what's up Thomas, hopefully this works well for you.
// This is a standalone program so you can try it out and
// implement it into your program.
// Grabs all lines with more than 5 characters and deletes with sed.
// usage: ./ThomasWest /home/sample.txt 

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  FILE *ptr_file;
  char buf[1000];
  char line[100];

  ptr_file =fopen("sample.txt","r+");

  if (!ptr_file)
    return 1;

  while (fgets(line,sizeof(line), ptr_file) != NULL)
  {
    if (strlen(line) > 5)
    {
    strtok(line, "\n");
    strtok(line, "\r");
    sprintf(buf, "sed -i '/%s/d' %s\n", line, argv[1]);
    //debug - printf("sed -i 's/%s//g' %s\n", line, argv[1]);
    system(buf);
    }
  }

    fclose(ptr_file);
    return 0;
}
```